# Azure B2C two apps in same tentant calling each other

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way for App1 registered under same tenant to call each other using B2C security? So for example use in App1 client id and secret go get token and then call App2 using POST with Bearer token to do something?
I was searching for something like that for some time but I do not see any way of doing that. I can get token using such code:

```
var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority($"{authority}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

var token = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(
    new string[] {
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    }
).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

But when I call other API using above authentication fails. Does anyone know any internet examples with something similar to above?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to expose the the api in your app registrations.

Go to the app registration of the api that you intend to call and create a scope:

[image: Expose Api in Azure Portal]

Then go to the app registry of the other app, the one that needs to call your exposed API, and add the scope to the API permissions:

[image: Add scope to the calling api app registration]

And lastly you need to grant admin consent to the added scope.

Now you can pass the scope to `AcquireTokenForClient` like this

```
var token = confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(
    new string[] {
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        "https://{YOUR_TENTANT}.onmicrosoft.com/{CLIENT_ID}/{SCOPE_NAME}",
    }
).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I did first part, but I did not know about second, thank you good man, I will try it

Comment: I forgot to add that you need to pass the scope to ```AcquireTokenForClient```. I updated my answer on how to do that. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else will need answer to above after searching for quite a while I found this tutorial:

https://techmindfactory.com/App-to-app-communication-with-azure-ad-b2c-access-tokens/

This basically answer all my questions, only thing missing in this tutorial was RoleClaimType setup, so inside AddJwtBearer there is need for:

```
jwtOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RoleClaimType = "roles"
};
```